How to instantiate a tool window on every opened IntelliJ window programmatically?
I'm working on a plugin for IntelliJ which consists of a tool window. My current approach it so instantiate it via:
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
        <toolWindow id="myID" icon="icon.svg" secondary="false" anchor="right"
                    factoryClass="package.MyToolWindowFactory">
        </toolWindow>
</extensions>

in plugin.xml. However I'm facing a problem that the tool window and all of its components are being instantiated after the user click on the tool window pane. How can I fix it?
Thx in advance :)

Your question is not clear. XML file does not contain a program code to instantiate anything. Please provide more context

@NadiaTarashkevich thank you for your answer. The MyToolWindowFactory contains the methods to instantiate the Tool Window. Unfortunately it is being called only after the users click on the Tool Window registered in the plugin.xml file. So my question regards not specifically the way of instantiating component but more the framework specific workflow.
